# ¿como guardar una relacion hasOne en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**ACTUALIZACION 1**

**En mi proyecto en laravel estoy trabajando con los siguientes modelos, Piece(principal), gag y program.
La relacion que existe entre piece y gag es una relacion hasOne.**

model piece:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Piece extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'program_id', 'gag_id', 'denomination', 'code', 'part_piece', 'time', 'observation'
    ];

    public function gag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Gag::class);
    } 

    public function program()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Program::class);
    }  

}
```

model gag:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Gag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'number_gag','diameter','type_gag','category_gag'
    ];

    public function piece()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Piece::class);
    }


}
```

Poseo un formulario donde puedo registrar información acerca de la fabricación de una pieza.
Dentro de mi formulario existe una seccion Mordaza, en el cual existe un input select desde donde se puede seleccionar una mordaza por su numero de mordaza, y se autocompletaran los campos de esa seccion.

**Mi problema esta al momento de guardar una pieza con su mordaza seleccionada.**

[image: formulario]

Por ejemplo si selecciono la mordaza numero 70(mordaza que ya esta registrada) ocurre que en el campo number_gag me guarda el id de la mordaza seleccionada vean la siguiente prueba que realice:

Dentro de mi metodo store verificando con dd($request->all()):

Request-consola:

```
array:14 [
  "_token" => "haHRN0y41Bh0BYRkJDq12GFICZ5UZ2NBSVcUY8q9"
  "denomination" => "buje d54"
  "code" => "6666-6666-6/6"
  "part_piece" => "1"
  "tools" => array:1 [
    0 => "6"
  ]
  "name_program" => "6666-6666-6/6"
  "number_program" => "6666"
  "part_program" => "1"
  "number_gag" => "5"
  "diameter" => "185"
  "type_gag" => "EXTERIOR"
  "category_gag" => "PASANTE"
  "time" => "1:01:01"
  "observation" => null
]
```

Se puede observar que el campo number_gag de la seccion mordaza llega el id de la mordaza que estoy seleccionando, y ese id es el que se guarda en mi tabla gags

```
 "number_gag" => "5"
```

lo correcto es que en el campo number_gag quede guardado el numero de mordaza = 70 y no su id=5 como en este caso.

metodo store:

```
 public function store(SavePieceRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                //  Transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();              

                // $this->authorize('create', new Piece);


                $gags = Gag::create($request->all());            

                $program = Program::create($request->all());

                $piece = $program->piece()->create([
                    'denomination' => $request['denomination'],
                    'code'         => $request['code'],
                    'time'         => $request['time'],
                    'part_piece'   => $request['part_piece'],         
                    'program_id'   => $program->id,         
                    'gag_id'       => $gags->id     

                ]);

                dd($request->all());

                $piece->syncTools($request->get('tools'));



                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }    
    }
```

formulario: (select)

```
                    {!! Form::label('number_gag', 'Mordaza') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </div>        
                        {!! Form::select('number_gag', $number_gag, $piece->gag['number_gag'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'number_gag', 'placeholder' => 'Mordaza']) !!}                     
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Que es lo que puede estar sucediendo?

**ACTUALIZACION 2**

realice un print_r($gags) dentro de mi metodo store justo aca:

```
  $gags = Gag::create($request->all());     
                print_r($gags);
```

el resultado es el siguiente:

```
App\Gag Object
(
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => number_gag
            [1] => diameter
            [2] => type_gag
            [3] => category_gag
        )

    [connection:protected] => mysql
    [table:protected] => gags
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 1
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [number_gag] => 1
            [diameter] => 660
            [type_gag] => EXTERIOR
            [category_gag] => PASANTE
            [updated_at] => 2020-03-06 12:12:10
            [created_at] => 2020-03-06 12:12:10
            [id] => 15
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [number_gag] => 1
            [diameter] => 660
            [type_gag] => EXTERIOR
            [category_gag] => PASANTE
            [updated_at] => 2020-03-06 12:12:10
            [created_at] => 2020-03-06 12:12:10
            [id] => 15
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [timestamps] => 1
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )

)
```

Comment: Por favor ver actualización!

Comment: A ver si entendí, lo que vos decis es que para guardar, te llega el id del select y no el valor del option? es eso lo que te pasa?

Comment: @Cribelo si si, el select me muestra los numeros de mordaza disponibles, pero al seleccionar un numero de mordaza y guardar, me esta guardando el id("ubicacion") de donde se encuentra ese numero de mordaza

Comment: @Cribelo a $number_gag lo paso desde mi metodo create de esta manera 'number_gag' => Gag::pluck('number_gag','id')

Comment: Lo normal es que cuando en web, generas un select, con options, al hacer post, osea enviar el formulario, se envia el id del option seleccionado, fijate de hacer un print_r ($request) en el metodo store, a ver si en algun lado esta el texto del select y no el id.

Comment: {!! Form::select('number_gag', $number_gag, $piece->gag['number_gag'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'number_gag', 'placeholder' => 'Mordaza']) !!}
Si cambias 
'id' => 'number_gag',
por el campo que queres que envie?

Comment: @Cribelo id=number_gag es el nombre de mi campo. O en todo caso no te entiendo por que nombre de campo cambiar

Comment: id=1 Numero 54
id=2 Numero 72,
vos queres guardar en la base de datos "54" y no "1"?
ese es el problema?

Comment: @Cirbelo si exacto, voy a mostrar el print_r($gags) de mi metodo store, revisa mi actualizacion

Comment: @Cribelo como solucionaria el problema con el select? Para que al seleccionar una mordaza me guarde su numero y no el id.

Comment: Creo que en ese caso hay un error de modelo de base de datos, si el numero 54 tiene un id, en este caso de ejemplo 1, debes guardar 1, y cuando tengas que mostrar el numero 54, al tener el id, tenes que hacer un join con esa tabla y que te traiga el 54.
Porque si recibís el "54", en id que pones? no podés dejar en nulo una relación, se entiende?

Comment: @Cribelo no comprendo exactamente, tengo mal configurado el select? mi metodo create? O el problema esta en mi metodo store al guardar la relacion entre piece y gag?

Comment: No, nada de código esta mal, si tenes un select (combo) , se guarda el id del valor seleccionado, no el valor seleccionado, para eso es un select, para guardar de opciones especificas, pero se guarda el id...al tener el id tenes el valor, osea, al tener id tenes el valor que es 54.

Comment: @Cribelo entonces para dejar claro, quieres decir que el funcionamiento es correcto? Si es asi en la imagen que subi del select ademas de mostrar el numero en este caso 54 tambien me esta mostrando 1 que el que guardo anteriormente y corresponde a su posicion, eso esta bien ?  En ese caso no quiero que muestre 1. Quisas la solucion es una tabla pivote y una relacion de muchos a muchos, aunque siempre voy a ingresar en el formulario solo un numero de mordaza  por pieza

Comment: Mira en la documentación supongo que lo tiene mal planteado el código https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: Hola @Janpweb supones que el error que tenia es porque tenia mal configurada mi relacion? que el campo number_gag guardara el numero y no el id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dices que llenas el select con las mordazas (`Gag`) disponibles.
En el controller:

```
$number_gag = Gag::pluck('number_gag','id');
```

Y en la vista:

```
{!! Form::select('number_gag', $number_gag, $piece->gag['number_gag'],...) !!}
```

Y el usuario selecciona una mordaza existente para la pieza (`Piece`) que está creando.

Entonces cuando guardas en base de datos, no crees una nueva mordaza.
Quita o comenta esta línea:

```
// $gags = Gag::create($request->all());
```

Cuando creas la pieza, relaciona la pieza con la mordaza a la que pertenece, asignando la id que te llega en el request, a la llave foránea que tienes en BD.

```
$program->piece()->create([..., 'gag_id' => $request['number_gag'] ]);
```

---

Otro tema.

La relación **`hasOne`** entre `Gag` (**mordaza**) y `Piece` (**pieza**).

Si **UNA mordaza** sólo puede tener **UNA pieza** (`hasOne`), al `select` lo deberías llenar con las **mordazas que NO tengan relacionada una pieza**, o sea que esté disponible.

Lo puedes lograr con Eloquent [consultando la ausencia de relación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence):

```
$mordazas_disponibles = Gag::doesntHave('piece')->pluck('number_gag','id');
```

Y llenando el select con sólo las disponibles:

```
{!! Form::select('number_gag', $mordazas_disponibles, $piece->gag['number_gag'],...) !!}
```

Es más, también sería mejor validar la ausencia de la relación antes de guardar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba seguro que lo que yo intentaba hacer se podia realizar, pero no entendia donde estaba mi error, es mas estaba convencido que en realidad necesitaba esta linea: ```$gags = Gag::create($request->all());```, deberia prestar mas antencion con la depuracion de codigo.

Comment: me hiciste dudar con la relacion que estoy creando entre pieza y mordaza, quisas no estoy comprendiendo la relación que deben tener estos modelos, pero el funcionamiento es asi:  un mismo numero de mordaza (gag)  puede estar en la pieza "eje", y tambien puede estar en la pieza "valvula", pero en mi formulario en la seccion  mordaza siempre voy a utilizar un solo numero de mordaza por pieza creada, se entiende?, con tu ultima aclaracion me hizo pensar en si es correcta la relacion que estoy utilizando, que opinas?

Comment: Entonces no hagas eso último que agregué. Si una mordaza (gag) puede estar en la pieza "eje", y tambien puede estar en la pieza "valvula",  la relación es una a muchos, cambiá la relación `piece()` en el modelo Gag a `hasMany` y listo

Comment: Ok esa es la relacion correcta

Answer (score 0):

Con la aclaracion de @porloscerros Ψ he entendido donde se encontraba mi error, simplemente debia de quitar esta linea en mi metodo store,`$gags = Gag::create($request->all());`, lo que en realidad pasaba es que cuando el usuario seleccionaba una mordaza existente para la pieza (Piece) que está creando, cuando guardaba en mi base de datos, se creaba una nueva mordaza.
Mi metodo store paso a quedar asi:

```
public function store(SavePieceRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                //  Transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();              

                // $this->authorize('create', new Piece);

                $program = Program::create($request->all());

                $piece = $program->piece()->create([
                    'denomination' => $request['denomination'],
                    'code'         => $request['code'],
                    'time'         => $request['time'],
                    'part_piece'   => $request['part_piece'],         
                    'gag_id'       => $request['number_gag'],         
                    'program_id'   => $program->id                     
                ]);                           

                $piece->syncTools($request->get('tools'));

                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }    
    }
```